# Best way to pass JS/ css info to a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I am sure this is so easy and I'm just a huge huge noob. I have a form on a PHP page, and it has a few normal form elements (1 textarea, 1 text field).

I am also dynamically adding 100 small images to the page, which are random, and I am using JQuery to let someone select or deselect these images:

Here is the html that loops 100 times to display the images:

```
<div class='avatar'><img class='avatar_image' src='$this_profile_image' name='$thisfriend'></div>
```

and here is the Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".avatar_image").click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("red");
        });
});
</script>
```

What I want to do is, when the form is submitted, have the script that processes it be able to tell which of those 100 images is selected (so it's class will be "red" instead of "avatar_image"). I am blanking on this.

Comment: How are you adding the 100 images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add hidden inputs with some kind of identifiers for those images, and toggle the state of those inputs based on the image selected-ness. Something like this:

```
Change your image markup:
<div class='avatar'>
   <img class='avatar_image' src='$this_profile_image' name='$thisfriend'>
   <input type="hidden" name="avatar_image[]" value="$this_profile_image" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

---

```
Change jQuery binding (and use event delegation, maybe pick a better container than document.body):
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        var selClass = 'red';
        $(document.body).on('click', ".avatar_image", function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $inp = $this.siblings('input[type="hidden"]');
                var isSelected = $this.hasClass(selClass), willBeSelected = !isSelected;
                $this.toggleClass(selClass);
                if(willBeSelected) {
                    $inp.removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    $inp.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

---

```
Read the submitted data in PHP (assuming you're submitting via a POST form):
$selectedImages = $_POST['avatar_image'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a ID to each image, when its clicked grab the id and then inject it into a hidden textfield

```
<input type="hidden" name="avatar" id="avatar" value="" />


$(".avatar_image").click(function() {

     $(this).toggleClass("red");

     //assign its id to the hidden field value
     $("input[name='avatar']").attr('value', $(this).attr('id')); 

     // pass that to your DB 
});
```

I presume your using ajax to grab this data back

```
success : function(callback){
     $("image[id*='"+callback.avatar+"']").addClass('red');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

PHP: Add the id for the friend to the html you had

```
<div class='avatar'>
    <img class='avatar_image' src='$this_profile_image' name='$thisfriend' data-id='$thisFriendsId>
</div>
```

JS: Create an empty array. Use each function to go through push the selected id into your array. Then use post to submit to your php.

```
selected = [];
$(function(){
    $(".avatar_image").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("red");
    });
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        $('.red').each(function(){
            var selectedId = $(this).data('id');
            selected.push(selectedId);       
        });
    $.post ('http://mysite.com/process.php', selected, function() { alert('succes!'); });
    });
​});​
```